# .net user control and page binding

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net, updatepanel, ascx

I have a block of code that contains an updatepanel and gridview that I use repeatedly in 5 different .aspx files. Instead of trying to maintain all 5. I was hoping to create a user control that I could just include in each page.

After starting to write it, I realized that it might not work. The issue is, I will need to bind database data to the updatepanel and gridview inside the usercontrol using Eval. But I don't think this is possible since the code will now be in a .ascx file.

So I was wondering if there is anyway to solve this.

Thanks!

Comment: its not a good idea to make a grid as usercontrol instead if you are smart enough make your own grid control from scratch lol.

Comment: why is it not a good idea? If I have the same block of code(that happens to contain a gridview) in 5 different pages, why can't it be inside a user control?  Is it a databinding issue?  Because that's where I am getting stuck. -thanks

Comment: I think its is better to PASS the Database query information to your UserControl and then use that info INSIDE your UserControl to load from DB. It is NOT necessary to DESIGN your own grid, thats just ludicrous! Post your common code block for the 5 pages and I'm sure a solution can be found.